# Rails 4 concerns: Give class instance variables to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activesupport-concern

With Rails concerns I can give my model class methods and instance methods through modules by including them. No blog entry or thread that I've found mentions how I can include variables in my model though.

Specifically I would like to give my including model a class instance variable `@question`, but I don't know where to put the declaration in the module so it is applied. I would also like the class instance variable to be overridden if  the model itself declares that variable.

Does the `ActiveSupport::Concern` module actually care about variables at all?

```
module ContentAttribute
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def foo
        p "hi"
    end

    module ClassMethods

        # @question = "I am a generic question." [doesn't work]

        def bar
            p "yo"
        end
    end
end 

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
    include ContentAttribute

    # @question = "Specific question"; [should override the generic question]
end
```

Comment: Can you add an `included` block and put `@question = ...` inside?

Comment: You mean like `included do; @question = "This is a generic question."; end` ? No, I still get a `NoMethodError` on `Video.question` (I defined an `attr_accessor :question` in the video model.)

Comment: How about adding `attr_accessor :question` in the included block

Comment: Nope, still the same. I doubted that would have changed anything.

Comment: Video.question is a class method, it should throw an error

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
module ContentAttribute
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    self.question = "I am a generic question."
  end

  module ClassMethods
    attr_accessor :question
  end

end
```

Then, in video...

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ContentAttribute
  self.question = "Specific question"
end
```

Comment: Isn't `after_initialize` called when an object is created? Wouldn't make your solution `question` an instance variable?

Comment: Yes - it would be an instance variable.  when they start with @, they are also instance variables.  Are you trying to create class variables?

Comment: Yes, I want to to create a _class_ instance variable (as stated in the title of my question). One that I can call with `Video.question`.

Comment: Sorry about that - I hadn't heard of class variables referred to as _class instance _variables, learned something new.

Comment: In fact I had learned about this notion on stackoverflow. There are "real" class variables like `@@question` and there are class _instance_ variables (since in ruby even classes are objects), like `@question`. You have to distinguish between them because they behave different.

Comment: Now unfortunately, your altered answer is about class variables and not class _instance_ variables. ^^

Comment: I see.  Trying one last answer.  This one has a slight problem, though.  A subclass will not get the default question without including the concern.  It's nil for a subclass, but otherwise works for the including classes.

Comment: That's what I've been looking for and it works. As I will not do any subclassing this is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Also I found out that this behaviour is indeed enabled by the `ActiveSupport::Concern` module. Doing something aequivalent with the `self.included(base)` method of a module will not work.